# How do i share or send a ward to my partner?

Tags: dota-2

Since the Reborn update, I can't mix my ward and share/give to another buddy. I used to do it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + left click the ward and give to my friend. But now, I just can't. It just gets planted when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + left click on his hero.

E.g: I buy 2 wards and I want to give just 1 to another buddy. I have to buy one, then give to him and then buy one more for me.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your ctrl key might not be registering in the game. Can you try to level up your skill with ctrl? For example, ctrl-q should level up your skill mapped to q key. If it's not, this might be the reason. And you don't have quickcast open for your item slots do you?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Absolutely i can up my skills with ctrl. I think i have some quickcast keys configured like ALT + 1, ALT + 2, ALT + 3 and etc.

Comment: I think it's not from quickcast but just to make sure, you press three keys to give the ward, ctrl, 1(ward item key) and left click, right? Does it get planted when you press ctrl+1, or ctrl+1 and left click? If it gets planted before the click, it might be related to quickcast. Also, did you do some autoexec.cfg stuff? If you did, it's on Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg folder. Try again after deleting that.

Answer (score 3):

As of the current patch (7.06f), you just Ctrl + click on the ward, then click on your teammate.

Answer (score -1):

You can drop the wards by dragging the wards to any ground and let your partner take it or you can directly drag the wards to your partner.

Comment: Not works if you have more then 1 ward but want to give only one to your teammate. So you miss point of question.